# How to stop a an asynchronous function immediately at a certain time?

Tags: javascript, date, asynchronous

I want to run a script like this:

```js
while(Date.now() < dateToStop){
    doSomething()
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
    doSomething()
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
}
```

The only thing is, I want to exit the loop the "instant" `Date.now() < dateToStop` is false, whereas this function could exit 4 seconds after due to its asynchronous nature nature.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You'll have to poll more often than 2 seconds if you want a tighter exit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solve this using maths:

```
let millisecondsLeft = (dateToStop.getTime() - date.Now().getTime());

while(millisecondsLeft > 0) {
     await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, Math.min(millisecondsLeft, 2000));
     millisecondsLeft = (dateToStop.getTime() - date.Now().getTime());
     if(millisecondsLeft > 0) {
         doSomething();
     }
     millisecondsLeft = (dateToStop.getTime() - date.Now().getTime());
     if(millisecondsLeft > 0) {
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, Math.min(millisecondsLeft, 2000));
     }
     millisecondsLeft = (dateToStop.getTime() - date.Now().getTime());
     if(millisecondsLeft > 0) {
          doSomething();
     }
     millisecondsLeft = (dateToStop.getTime() - date.Now().getTime());
}
```

This is getting unweildy, so let's create a separate pause function,
that returns `true` if there's any time left:

```
function pause(millsecondsPause, maxDateTime) {
    const remainingTime = (maxDateTime.getTime() - date.Now().GetTime());
    if(remainingTime < 0) {
        return Promise.resolve(false);
    } else if (remainingTime < millisecondsPause) {
        return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, remainingTime))
           .then(() => false);
    } else {
        return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, milliscondsPause))
           .then(() => true);
    }
}


while(await pause(2000, dateToStop)) {
     doSomething();
     if(!await pause(2000, dateToStop)) {
        break;
     }
     doSomething();
}
```